# restore multiple SQL Server databases from single dump file

Tags: sql-server

we have received a single dump (.dmp) file created for multiple databases. Could someone please tell me

1. how do you create this single file ? and
2. more importantly how do I restore these databases to a new sql server instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't check at the moment as not at my DB server, however if it's what I think it is, try right clicking on your SERVER name in SQL Management studio, navigate to tasks, and backup/restore databases.

This may also be an option on individual tables, containing multiple tables.